# aws eks istio how do we test end to end TLS traffic?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio

I used https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/secure-end-to-end-traffic-on-amazon-eks-using-tls-certificate-in-acm-alb-and-istio/ TLS traffic on aws using istio

My question is how do I conclusively test a BEFORE and AFTER scenario

- before end to end tls was implemented the tls traffic terminated at
  load balancer -> How do I prove it and test it?
- after end to end tls  was implemented the tls traffic terminated at
  pods --> how do I prove    it and test it?

Thanks